# Installing Google IME

Tags: multimedia, language-support

Can I install Google Transliteration IME (Input method editor which allows users to enter text in one of the supported languages using a roman keyboard),on Ubuntu 12.04 ?. I need to type in Sinhalese(The language of Sri Lanka). I'm a novice on Ubuntu. Please.... I need your help.

P S : Please note that my question is NOT ABOUT "Google transliteration". i.e.  Type a word in English and press SPACE to transliterate.

Comment: Now you can use [Google Input Tools extension for Google Chrome webpage](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-input-tools-by-goo/mclkkofklkfljcocdinagocijmpgbhab?hl=en).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though it's only made for windows, but you could try running it within Wine.

Wine is software which lets you run programs designed for Windows within Operating Systems such as Ubuntu and Mac OSX.

There's some support for it within the Ubuntu Community Documentation section. [See Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the sinhala phonetic keyboard, if you're looking for a way to type; that uses the phonetic equivalents of the roman keyboard you are using and gives the sinhala letter,

for example "D" becomes "ද" and likewise. after installing look in the ubuntu help in your desktop for setting up a composite key. If you need more help mention that in the comments,

Answer (score 0):

Hi there Noah Diaz-

```
     Your question about Google IME I belive I can answer, what I know that Google is known for all systems. Even Mac OS X, Windows and finally, Linux.
```

Mac OS X: Firefox should automaticly be found using the browser. It should be your
home page. Search the Google IME File, Download it and if you just got it, then
it should be fast download. And wont take up much space of your computer.

Windows of any kind: Firefox should automaticly be found using the browser. It should be your
home page. Search the Google IME File, Download it and if you just got it, then
it should be fast download. And wont take up much space of your computer.

Linux: Use your browser to find google search in google Google IME.
It should take you to it. Then, Download the file.